# Swift - UIScrollView Extension- Add Image to A UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, parallax

When I use the StoryBoard, I can add an UIImageView to UITableView like this:

[image]

I am trying to write an UIScrollView extension to add a parallax image into a UITableView which can be reused for all the tables easily. Here my code to add image:

```
 extension UIScrollView {

  func addParallaxImage(image image: UIImage, height: CGFloat) {
    let myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    myImageView.image = image
    myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

    myImageView.frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    myImageView.frame.size.height = height
    myImageView.frame.origin.y = 0

    self.addSubview(myImageView)

  }

}
```

Function usage:

```
tableView.addParallaxImage(image: UIImage(named: "pets")!, height: 100)
```

However, my image overlaps the table.

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30885150/5100253 mb this will help you

Comment: @KonstantinKryzhanovsky Thanks! I read it before, but found nothing. I'll read them again. =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for your case is used tableview header and here the most usable libs:-

[CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout)

[ParallaxTableViewHeader](https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader)

[VGParallaxHeader](https://github.com/stoprocent/VGParallaxHeader)

[APParallaxHeader](https://github.com/apping/APParallaxHeader)

Take care not all libs support Swift, I hope I help you.

Comment: Thanks! Let me check! Coz I am not good add Objective-C much, so need a time to understand their code. In addition, I want to write my own lib, not implement someone's else.

Comment: Thanks, perfect go ahead.

Comment: @AnLê Accept the answer it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna reused the cell. 
You can try to add the ImageView into your tableViewCell.
By the way, the header and the footer can be reused too.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't want to reuse cell. I am using reuse cell now. However, I want to improve it.

Comment: Try to make tableView contentInset .
`tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)`

Comment: If you want the Image behind the table, you should add ImageView to the superView first .

Comment: I create my table by drag an UITableView into Xib file. I just want to impact the table by code in extension. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addSubview try using insertSubview(_ view: UIView, atIndex index: Int)
with index 0, so it won't be above your cells.

Comment: It only make my image under the table. It means you can see the image, coz the table will overlap it. :(

Comment: If you don't want them to overlap, you'll have to put the picture in tableView header, so it's not possible as an extension on scroll view.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I want something like Storyboard way. :3

Comment: Storyboard way is to use table view header, so that would be exactly like storyboard way.